# Trying to complete a simple Dial action, and record the call - Twilio - have tried these 4 things

Tags: php, twilio

I am trying to make a Dial/Conference call in Twilio and to record it.

This works without error (Dial/Conference), but it doesn't record:

```
$response = new Response();
$dial = new Dial();
$conference = new Conference('name_of_conference_call', array('startConferenceOnEnter'=>"true", 'endConferenceOnExit'=>'false'));
$dial->append($conference);
$response->append($dial);
$response->Respond();
```

I just can't get the record element working. I only want it to record so it shows a recording in https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/recordings, I don't need the recording on my server, or any record in a database.

I have seen this, but it doesn't resolve it: [Twilio - Dial with Record attribute error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17427246/twilio-dial-with-record-attribute-error)

I have tried these, but always get the same "Error on line 1 of document : Premature end of file. Please ensure that the response body is a valid XML document." error.

(1) Adding 'record'=>true on either Dial or Conference causes that error:

```
$dial = new Dial(array('record'=>true));
```

OR

```
$conference = new Conference('name_of_conference_call', array('startConferenceOnEnter'=>"true", 'endConferenceOnExit'=>'false', 'record' => true));
```

(2) Adding the record=true parameter mentioned above and then also specifying an action (for Dial) or a eventCallbackUrl (for Conference) parameter. The URL (on my server) has exactly this PHP:

```
<?php
header("content-type: text/xml");
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
    <Hangup/>
</Response>
```

I think this should be okay, as I don't want it to do anything else. I only want the recording in https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/recordings, I don't need the recording on my server, or any record in a database.

Regardless, doing this causes the error mentioned above too.

(3) I then tried using the addRecord method in the Dial and Conference classes (separately), example:

```
(a) Without parameter:

    $conference->addRecord();
```

AND

```
(b) With parameter:

    $conference->addRecord(array('eventCallbackUrl' => 'http://domain.com/file_to_handle.php'));
```

(4) I also tried using the addRecord method on the Response class. This just got ignored, and didn't actually error.

```
$response->addRecord(); // Etc.
$response->Respond();
```

So, I just need to be able to record a call and see it in https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/recordings

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

The `record` attribute on the `<Conference>` noun does not take a boolean value.  Instead if you want to tell Twilio to record the conference, set the attributes value to `record-from-start`.

The Conference noun docs have more details and if you scroll all the way to the bottom a TwiML example of using the record attribute.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#attributes-record
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/conference#examples-7

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. What would help a lot is if I knew whether you must specify the action/eventCallbackUrl attribute. I don't see why I need to. I just want to record on Twilio and nothing else. Can I leave that attribute and just add the record one? Knowing this will help as I can narrow down my testing. If I must specify the action/eventCallbackUrl attribute then is a simple <Hangup/> only response (like shown in my question) enough?